# How to show the correct name object in Django admin instead 'XXX object'

Tags: django, python-3.x

I've two apps in my Django Project and I created an ManytoManyField relationship between then. However, when I check it on my admin site, the references appears showing the model name plus object inside the Many to Many box.

I already tried write a **str** in my model as you can see below:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.course.name)
```

Below there is my models code.

```
from django.db import models
from cursos.models import Course

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    course = models.ManyToManyField(Course, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.course.name)
```

[image: The image shows the page where I can register and relate some courses to a new person.]

Comment: You need to implement a `__str__` for the `Course` model, not the `Person` model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This part of the form deals with editing the `ManyToManyField`. It will use the `__str__` of the model that is referenced.

In order to thus change the textual representation, you need to implement the `__str__` of the `Course` model, like:

```
class Course(models.Model):  # Course model, not Person
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Setting the `__str__` of a person to `self.course.name` does not seem correct, since you probably do not want to represent a `Person` by the name of its courses. Furthermore since this is a `ManyToManyField`, it will not work anyway.

> **Note**: usually the name of `ManyToManyField`s is *plural*, so `courses`, instead of `course`, since it is basically a *collection* of `Course`s, not a single `Course`.